# Nginx proxy pass to localhost Gunicorn returns 50x error unexpectedly

Tags: nginx, configuration, django, proxypass, gunicorn

I have a very basic set up with nginx installed with a django app running on a gunicorn server. The gunicorn conf is simple and below:

```
exec gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application \
    --workers 5
    --reload
```

I've set up nginx server to proxy_pass all incoming traffic on the default server to 127.0.0.1:8000. However, when I go to the IP address of the server, I see the default nginx 404 screen. So I am assuming that the traffic was proxy passed by the nginx server but somehow was not properly routed and no response was given back which forces nginx to return a 404. What exactly am I doing wrong on either the gunicorn or nginx configuration here? For reference, below is my full nginx.conf file as well:

```
user nginx; worker_processes auto; 

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log; 
pid /run/nginx.pid;

    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic. include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024; }

    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*

    upstream app_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

    }
```

EDIT: After more closely looking into the error message in this setup I realize it's not a 404 and it's actually a 50x so something must definitely be wrong in the way the 2 services are communicating with each other. Going to the gunicorn endpoint alone produces the django app with no problems. As does going to the default nginx splace screen before adding the proxy_pass parameter. Any help, what exactly am I missing. Thanks

Comment: Could you share error logs?

Comment: @AlexanderT yes thanks the error for the requests to localhost is "failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream," So probably a user perm issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own issue. Basically for fedora based solutions running nginx you must open up access to upstream connections to all users that are not root. You can do that with this command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Obviously run above as root. Further info can be found on this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx